TMS AdvWebBrowser not initializing
I have a TMS AdvWebBrowser component. Initially it showed that the WebView2Loader_x86.dll was missing. (This showed on the component when dropping it on a form) I installed the Evergreen, and the error went away.
The problem now is when you run the application, I get the following messages:


Is it a x86 or x64 app? Did you provide the correct DLL version to your app?

Do not post screenshots of text. What you have there could have been easily copied to the clipboard via Ctrl+C.

@DelphiCoder it is a x86 app, and yes the correct dll version
